# Magento 2 delete custom order status

Tags: magento2.3

I have added custom order status using the data patch by reference to the below link.

[Add new Order Statuses to Magento 2.3 using declarative scheme approach](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264476/add-new-order-statuses-to-magento-2-3-using-declarative-scheme-approach)

Now I want to delete that custom order status. How can I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

There are no way to delete the custom order statuses from Magento admin but you can delete it from Database tables

```
sales_order_status  
sales_order_status_label
```